# How to access variables in another scope inside a function using closure in javascript?

Tags: javascript, scope, closures

I have the following function `makeStopwatch` that I am trying to work through to better understand javascript closures:

```
var makeStopwatch = function() {
  var elapsed = 0;
  var stopwatch = function() {
    return elapsed;
  };
  var increase = function() {
    elapsed++;
  };

  setInterval(increase, 1000);
  return stopwatch;
};

var stopwatch1 = makeStopwatch();
var stopwatch2 = makeStopwatch();

console.log(stopwatch1());
console.log(stopwatch2());
```

When I `console.log` the calls to `stopwatch1` and `stopwatch2` I get `0` returned each time respectively.

As I understand the intended functionality of `makeStopwatch` the variable `elapsed` would be `0` if returned by the inner function `stopwatch`. The inner function `increase` increments the variable `elapsed`. Then `setInterval` calls `increase` after a delay of 1 second. Finally, `stopwatch` is returned again this time with the updated value which is expected to be `1`.

But this doesn't work because inside `makeStopwatch`, the inner `stopwatch`, `increase`, and `setInterval` functions are all in independent scopes of one another?

How can I revise this to work as I understand it so that `elapsed` is incremented and that value is closed over and saved so that when I assign `makeStopwatch` to variable `stopwatch1` and call `stopwatch1` the updated value is returned?

Comment: Your code is working.  Also, CodeSchool?  (I put your code exactly as you have it into the console. Run `console.log(stopwatch1())` multiple times.)

Comment: The code as posted will always log 0 for both as the console.log will occur within 1 second of the stopwatch being created.  Try wrapping the bottom two lines in a `setTimeout(console.log(stopwatch1()), 2000);` `setTimeout(console.log(stopwatch2()), 4000);` for example to see that the stopwatches are indeed "running"

Comment: I guess I'm confused because looking at the body of function  `increase` and how `elapsed` is incremented, as well as taking into my perception of what a real-world stopwatch does, I expect the console.logs to show that the stopwatch is indeed counting upwards.

Comment: @ChadF, shouldn't running `console.log(stopwatch1())` multiple times show the stopwatch "counting" upwards and so I'd get `1` then `2` then `3` and so on?

Comment: @JaromandaX, I tried the code you suggested and I'm still logging out a bunch of zeroes. Evidently, I don't understand what this code is supposed to do? Why is it not outputting an increasing output like a stopwatch? How does the code as is make use of closure just to log out zeroes?

Comment: in your original code, you are console logging once, right when the stopwatch is created, of course you will get a zero - the value of elapsed is initialised to zero, therefore it's output as zero - after one second, it will be 1, after two seconds it'll be 2 and so on

Comment: @phizzy @Jaromanda's code is wrong: it should be `setTimeout(function() {console.log(stopwatch1())}, 2000);` and the same for `stopwatch2`.

Comment: @McBrainy, you are of course correct :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var makeStopwatch = function() {
  var elapsed = 0;

  // THIS stopwatch function is referenced later
  var stopwatch = function() {
    return elapsed;
  };

  var increase = function() {
    elapsed++;
  };
  // This setInterval will continue running and calling the increase function.
  // we do not maintain access to it.
  setInterval(increase, 1000);

  // THIS returns the stopwatch function reference earlier.  The only way
  // we can interact with the closure variables are through this function.
  return stopwatch;
};

var stopwatch1 = makeStopwatch();
// This runs the makeStopwatch function.  That function *RETURNS* the
// inner stopwatch function that I emphasized above.

console.log(stopwatch1());
// stopwatch1 is a reference to the inner stopwatch function.  We no longer
// have access to the elapsed variable or the function increase.  However
// the `setInterval` that is calling `increase` is still running.  So every
// 1000ms (1 second) we increment elapsed by 1.
```

So if were were to put all of the above code into the console, and then call `console.log(stopwatch1())` sporadically, it will console.log the number of seconds since we created the stopwatch.